# Rendering views, scaled @2x, renderInContext, iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, render

I have a view (called outPutView) that contains graphics, like uIImageViews and labels. I need to render an image of the outPutView and it's sub-views. I am using renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() to do so. Works fine, except that I need to scale the views. I am using a transform on the outPutView. This successfully scales the view and it's sub-views, but the transform does not render. While the views are scaled onscreen. the final render displays the vies at their original size, while the render context is at the target size (here @2x iPhone view size).

Thanks for reading!!

```
[outPutView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMake(2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0)];
CGSize renderSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width*2, self.view.bounds.size.height*2);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(renderSize);
[[outPutView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Suspect you'll have to render it to an image without the transform, then draw that image into another image, using the scaled size with `drawInRect:`. Although if you figure out a way to do it in one step, I'm all ears! The two step tango wastes memory and causes trouble for large views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by re-ordering my views. Actually adding another view between the output view: the view that the rendered context is taken from, and the view that is scaled via transform. It worked, but I have no idea why at this point. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Interesting. So if the transform is applied to a subview then it's applied in the `renderInContext:`? Quirky. Although if it works, it works. And that avoids having to apply transforms to the destination context, which in many situations will be undesirable.

Answer (score 10):

I've just made this work, although in the opposite direction (scaling down). Here's a summary of the relevant code:

```c
// destination size is half of self (self is a UIView)
float rescale = 0.5;
CGSize resize = CGSizeMake(self.width * rescale, self.height * rescale);

// make the destination context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(resize, YES, 0);

// apply the scale to dest context
CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rescale, rescale);

// render self into dest context
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

// grab the resulting UIImage
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

To scale up instead of down, it should be fine to have `rescale = 2`.